# Help with file download in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void imgbtn_BBDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Response.ContentType = "application/exe";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=bb.exe");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/Resources/bb.exe") );
Response.End();
    }
```

I want to download the bb.exe file which is inside a Resource folder. I have a login form in the same screen, instead of downloading the file, the username password validation is done and the validiation summary username and password is required is shown. what is wrong with the code. Or if these is any easy method to do, pls suggest. thanks

Comment: is the event wired up? what happens when you debug it?

Comment: Would it not be quicker and easier just to do a response.redirect or even a javascript redirect to the file for the download or am i being dense?

Comment: the username password validation is done and the validiation summary username and password is required is shown. doesn't even goes inside the imgbtn_BBDownload_Click when I do debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all controls on page are validated, since all controls validation group is same (i.e., blank). Add validation group to login / password / submit button controls. It will then validate only when u click login button but not download file click button.